# Artifactory - Variation in the size of the pom.xml for the jars which is manually uploaded

Tags: artifactory

Currently we are using the Artifactory version as 3.3.0. Whenever we upload the jars into artifactory the generated pom file is 1kb but the actual size of the pom file is 7 kb due to this build is failing and we are manually uploading the pom file which is tedious task. can anyone please help on this.

eg. If I upload the Spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE jars into Artifactory. In the local repository,  Spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE-pom file is 1KB but the actual size of the pom.xml is 7KB.

Following are the screenshot which explain the steps to upload the jars into Artrifactory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: You need to add more information. How are you uploading the JARs into Artifactory.
Why are you not using a remote repository on jcenter or maven central?

Comment: @ajeans,  As per the company norms, we need to have control on the jars that we are using. So we check the global offline mode. Hence we are manually uploading the jars.

Comment: That makes sense. So how do you upload the JARs to your repositories in this offline setting?

Comment: @ajeans, Please find the screenshot for the jar upload into Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. So my understanding is that you are uploading the JAR and telling Artifactory to generate a default POM for it (that is the last checkbox called "Also Deploy Jar's Internal POM / Generate Default POM"). As a result, you get a generated / wrong POM in Artifactory.
Can you try to upload manually the JAR, with that checkbox left unchecked, and then upload manually the correct POM that you have?